# Spring MVC: Difference between spring:message and request locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tags, locale

I'm having some inconsistency and I need some expert advice. I'm using Spring MVC 3.2

Having this beans:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="10" /> <!-- for easier development -->
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>
```

And two diferent message files:

```
messages.properties
messages_es.properties
```

When using spring tag  the locale resolves to "es" and uses messages_es as expected (it's my system lang).

However, if I try to get the locale programatically I always get "en". I've tried this options:

**Option 1:**

```
@Autowired
private LocaleResolver localeResolver;
....
localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
```

**Option 2:**

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

**Option 3:**

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
```

All of them result with "en" lang.

The question is, How do I get the locale used by spring:message tag ??

Acording to documentation,

> When a request comes in, the DispatcherServlet looks for a locale resolver, and if it finds one it tries to use it to set the locale. Using the RequestContext.getLocale() method, you can always retrieve the locale that was resolved by the locale resolver.

But all my texts in the final html are in "es" and this method returns "en"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll answer myself. I debugged it deep enought to find out that the problem was a missing property in ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource definition. Adding fallbackToSystemLocale = false and removing default locale in localeResolver now locale resolves to "es" in requests.

So far so good. Sadly the part of changing locale via "?lang=en" parameter doesn't work but thats another story.

**Resolution:**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />
```

and

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

Comment: Regarding the interceptor: declaring the interceptor as a bean it's not enough, you should register it, using the mvc:interceptor or the [simple url mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the locale can be accessed programmatically using `RequestContext.getLocale()` ([reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver)).

However, in a controller's `@RequestMapping` handler method, you can rely on Spring to obtain the Locale.
Since `Locale` is a [supported argument type](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods), just declaring a variable of type `Locale` as an argument of your controller method will allow you to access the current locale.

**Interceptors**
In the shown configuration, the locale interceptor is declared as a bean, but not registered as an interceptor. Try this, from the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor):

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or, starting with Spring 3.0 you can use the mvc:interceptors

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Tried with a parameter and still "en".

Comment: Good point! the mvc:interceptors solved the second issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The message tag is using the `RequestContext` to retrieve the `MessageSource` and the current `Locale`. This can be seen in the resolveMessage method in the MessageTag class:

```
return messageSource.getMessage(this.message, getRequestContext().getLocale());
```

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag.java

Comment: I debugged spring source code until this line and locale is "en" at this poing, however, the returned message is from the "es" message file! I'm totally lost :S